# MySQL Data Fabrication

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have a table that stores progress data between client to member and member to client for different  type of section;

[image]

I want to create a table that doesn't really exist in the database which display summary for client and member for different type of section. The purpose of that is to avoid making too many calls to database and getting everything I want in one go.

I am expecting a table that display data in the following way;

[image]

In the above table client is the id = 105446 from the first table and member is id  = 105407. The section column photo, references, meetings, engagement, and payments need to show regardless, if a data for the section exist for a the member type, then display the status in its column value otherwise, display "untounched", if not record of the section for the member type is found.

Any help is appreciated

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to think about renormalizing your data.

Comment: Search for "pivot" or "crosstab". This gets asked about once a week

Comment: @Cheruvian in which sense is this not normalized?